# Detect if stored proc delete ran

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

If I calling a stored proc how do i detect that it has completed succesfully on the server as right now im just doing a try catch which is not the best way of doing this.

```
public bool deleteTeam(Guid teamId)
{
    try
    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["uniteCms"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(cs.ToString());

        // the stored procedure
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
            "proc_unitecms_deleteTeam", myConnection);

        // 2. set the command object so it knows
        // to execute a stored procedure
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // 3. add parameter to command, which
        // will be passed to the stored procedure
        cmd.Parameters.Add(
            new SqlParameter("@ID", teamId));
        return true;

    } catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: return a value from the stored proc. Just write `select 1` as the last line of sproc, then to run it from your method call `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()` method. Read the value, if it is `1`, your sproc ran succesfully. Of course you can return different values depending on your try catch block in the sproc.

Comment: Why is `try-catch` not enough? If it is just about detecting an error, this should be enough. Do you want to know whether a specific condition in the stored procedure was met? You can use an `OUT` parameter that you set in the stored procedure for the later. In your code sample, there is no code that actually executes the stored procedure. Is this by accident?

Answer (score 2):

You can return the affected rows number and return -1 in case of catch a exception .

You forget the ExecuteNonQuery.

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
Int32 rowsAffected;
cmd.CommandText = "StoredProcedureName";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
sqlConnection1.Open();
rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConnection1.Close();
```